# Writing A Function Polymorphic In A Type Family

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

I was experimenting with type families yesterday and ran into an obstacle with the following code:

```
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

  class C a where
      type A a
      myLength :: A a -> Int

  instance C String where
      type A String = [String]
      myLength = length

  instance C Int where
      type A Int = [Int]
      myLength = length

  main = let a1 = [1,2,3]
             a2 = ["hello","world"]
         in print (myLength a1)
            >> print (myLength a2)
```

Here I have a type associated with class C and a function that calculates the length of the associated type. However the above code gives me this error:

```
 /tmp/type-families.hs:18:30:
     Couldn't match type `A a1' with `[a]'
     In the first argument of `myLength', namely `a1'
     In the first argument of `print', namely `(myLength a1)'
     In the first argument of `(>>)', namely `print (myLength a1)'
 /tmp/type-families.hs:19:30:
     Couldn't match type `A a2' with `[[Char]]'
     In the first argument of `myLength', namely `a2'
     In the first argument of `print', namely `(myLength a2)'
     In the second argument of `(>>)', namely `print (myLength a2)'
 Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

If, however I change "type" to "data" the code compiles and works:

```
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

  class C a where
      data A a
      myLength :: A a -> Int

  instance C String where
      data A String = S [String]
      myLength (S a) = length a

  instance C Int where
      data A Int = I [Int]
      myLength (I a) = length a

  main = let a1 = I [1,2,3]
             a2 = S ["hello","world"]
             in
               print (myLength a1) >>
               print (myLength a2)
```

Why does "length" not work as expected in the first case? The lines "type A String ..." and "type A Int ..." specify that the type "A a" is a list so myLength should have the following types respectively : "myLength :: [String] -> Int" or "myLength :: [Int] -> Int".

Comment: It looks like you may need a `{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances -#}` in there too, as `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`, and without the flag GHC expects instance heads to be built up of primitive type variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hm. Let's forget about types for a moment.

Let's say you have two functions:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM

a :: Int -> Float
a x = fromInteger (x * x) / 2

l :: Int -> String
l x = fromMaybe "" $ IM.lookup x im
  where im = IM.fromList -- etc...
```

Say there exists some value `n :: Int` that you care about. Given only the value of `a n`, how do you find the value of `l n`? You don't, of course.

How is this relevant? Well, the type of `myLength` is `A a -> Int`, where `A a` is the result of applying the "type function" `A` to some type `a`. However, `myLength` being part of a type class, the class parameter `a` is used to select which implementation of `myLength` to use. So, given a value of *some specific type `B`*, applying `myLength` to it gives a type of `B -> Int`, where `B ~ A a` and you need to know the `a` in order to look up the implementation of `myLength`. Given only the value of `A a`, how do you find the value of `a`? You don't, of course.

You could reasonably object that in your code here, the function `A` *is* invertible, unlike the `a` function in my earlier example. This is true, but the compiler can't do anything with that because of the *open world* assumption where type classes are involved; your module could, in theory, be imported by another module that defines its own instance, e.g.:

```
instance C Bool where
    type A Bool = [String]
```

Silly? Yes. Valid code? Also yes.

In many cases, the use of constructors in Haskell serves to create *trivially injective functions*: The constructor introduces a new entity that is defined only and uniquely by the arguments it's given, making it simple to recover the original values. This is precisely the difference between the two versions of your code; the data family makes the type function invertible by defining a new, distinct type for each argument.

Comment: @cammccann Thanks for the explanation. I guess I don't understand why , for example, the type of the "myLength" in "C Int" doesn't resolve to "[Int] -> Int" by virtue of being defined as part of the "C" typeclass.

Comment: @Deech: Well, it does; for `C Int`, `myLength` gets the type `[Int] -> Int`. The problem is that, in an expression like `myLength ([1, 2] :: [Int])`, there's no way to get from `[Int]` back to `A Int`, just like there's no way to get from `12.5` back to `5` (rather than `-5`) in my function `a`.

Comment: @cammccann I just changed "let a1 = [1,2,3]" to "let a1 = ([1,2,3] :: A Int)" and similarly to "a2" but I get the same errors. Since I have explicitly given the compiler "a1"'s type shouldn't it now correctly resolve?

Comment: @camcccann I think I just had pin-prick of clarity. Is it the case that even though I specify my "a1" to be "A Int" there could be any number of instances that have "type A Int = ..." as one of the instance members?

Comment: @Deech: Again, think of `A` as being a function you're applying to calculate a type. When you use it, the definition is expanded just like a type synonym; in fact, you can think of type families as being type synonyms that pattern match on their parameters and choose different implementations. In my first example, would you expect that writing `a 5` instead of `-12.5` would let you write a function that could distinguish it from `a (-5)`?

Comment: @Deech: There will only be one type given by `A Int`, but there could be other instances `A Foobar` such that `A Foobar` and `A Int` are the same type, such that it would be reasonable (and desired, in some cases) to apply `myLength` from the `Int` instance to something whose type is given by `A Foobar`.

Comment: @cammccann Awesome! I get it! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Deech: You're welcome. :] It's surprisingly counterintuitive for something so simple, since we're used to things that look like type constructors being automatically [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective), while type families aren't.

Comment: @cammccann Is any method to invoke myLength :: A a -> Int, where A is type family ?

Comment: @nickela: I don't think so. There's really no way for it to decide what type `a` to use; the discussion above is pretty much all there is to say on the matter. The class function needs to take at least one argument that lets GHC find the instance.